# How to send HTTP error code in Classic ASP with a HTTP subStatus?

Tags: asp-classic, http-headers, http-status-codes

In Classic ASP, I know that it's possible to return a **HTTP Error Header** by specifying the **.Status** property, like this :

```
Response.Status = "404 File Not Found"
```

But How can I return a more specific Error code **with a substatus**, for example 404.9 or 500.100 ?

I need to do that for testing purposes (as I know that the subStatus code is usually added by the server dynamically)

Comment: Have you tried `Response.Status = "404.9 File attribute hidden"`?

Comment: Judging by [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525844(v=vs.90).aspx) it only expects a *"three-digit number that indicates a status code"*, but my advice would be try it and see.

Comment: @Lankymart, Yes, I have tested it, but it does not seems to work.
The only way to "generate" an error is by trying to call a "test.yyy" file located on the website. As the file extension .yyy is not part of the IIS MimeMap, the static file handler will not serve it and then return a 404.3 error. This way, I can test my custom error pages.

Comment: In which case I'm not sure what to suggest, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So : It seems that It is only possible to generate "three-digit" HTTP errors from Classic ASP code.

So the Only way to test if your custom webpages are working, is to **call a "test.yyy" file** located on the website.

As the file extension .yyy is not part of the IIS MimeMap, the static file handler will not serve it and then return a 404.3 error. This way, I can test my custom error pages.
This example comes from this Microsoft Article : https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis

So for everyone needing to set very detailed error messages including the HTTP subcodes under IIS 7 / 8, here is the **"web.config"** file contents for your website : *(this file contains only a few entries, but you obviously can add entries for every HTTP code/subcode combination you want. Microsoft provides 56 error pages in C:\inetpub\custerr)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="5" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-5.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="4" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-4.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="3" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-3.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="2" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-2.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="1" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-1.html" />
            <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="0" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="E:\inetpub\vhosts\yourdomain.com\error_docs\404-0.html" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope it will help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

IIS will not log custom subcode in traffic logs.

Do not test for the subcode.  Test for the statusText property returned by the custom error.

Comment: IIS DOES logs the subcode (you just have to click the "IIS > ASP > Logging" icon to include this field into the log file.
If your server hit a "500.0", you will see 500 0 near the end of the line.
If your server hit a "500.19", you will see 500 19 near the end of the line.

Comment: I configured a test page to return a "404.19 Wrong Droids" and saw "404 0" in my logs.  That was the basis of my answer.  My answer was also based on how I believed you were testing--using some kind of ServerXMLHTTP component or AJAX request.

Comment: Ok, i better understand your answer ! You made "assumptions" on the way I was testing it .. that... well... eh.. were not exact ;) I had tested the same way you did it : using a simple .asp test page. And The fact that your logs displays 404.0 reveal that IIS dropped the subcode sent by the ASP code, thus confirming the fact that Classic ASP can only generate 3-digit errors. Thank you ! ;)